# Find and Replace in Google Sheet Macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, replace, regexp-replace

I have a Google sheet file where each month I need to copy some data, and they are copied like that:
"-1 200,00 EUR" OR "=+80,66 EUR"
I would like to create a macro that automatically replaces:

```
- "," with "."
- " EUR" with ""
- " " (shortspace) with ""
```

The problem is that the value *=+80,66 EUR* appears like a formula and so as *#ERROR* and when I try to replace it, it doesn't work. This is the script I wrote:

```
function ReplaceH() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange("D1:E49");
  var data  = range.getValues();

  for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
      data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace('=+', '');
      data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace(' ', '');
      data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace('EUR', '');
      data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace(',', '.');
    }
  }
  range.setValues(data);
};
```

Comment: Screenshot of your sheet please.

Comment: What do you want the final string to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=SUBSTITUTE(regexextract(A1,"[\-0-9, ]+")," ","")
```

Comment: I tried       data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace(RegExp('[0-9, ]+'),' ','');

but it deletes almost everything, and it doesn't solve the #error issue!

Comment: ok, what i came up with is a custom function. I will also do inside a script.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a script, use

```
function ReplaceH() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange("B1:B2");
  var data  = range.getValues();

  var regExp = new RegExp("[\-+0-9, ]+");

  for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
      var x = regExp.exec(data[row][col]);
      data[row][col] = x[0].replace(/ /g,'')
    }
  }
  range.setValues(data);
};
```

Comment: I get " TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null" from the line
data[row][col] = x[0].replace(/ /g,'')

Comment: I have updated the regex https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DoQx1Jme5bawib7Re128nXUVAixq5AT7em0PcKUe7f0/edit?usp=sharing